# Format text color of table cells based on condition

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I calculated and displayed the  **expiry days** for each product. Now I want to format the days(text) color.

Suppose the default color should be orange, but if the days is less than 15 the color should change to red.

**cell to be formatted :**

```
 <td> @Html.DisplayFor( modelItem => (Convert.ToDateTime(item.ExpiryDate) -  DateTime.Now).Days) </td>
```

**View:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this (untested):

```
    @var daysToExpire = Convert.ToDateTime(item.ExpiryDate) -  DateTime.Now).Days;
    @if (daysToExpire < 15)
    {
        <td style="color: red;">@daysToExpire</td>
    }
    else
    {
        <td style="color: orange;">@daysToExpire</td>
    }
```

You could also do this by composing it as part of the viewmodel in your controller then it would look cleaner:

```
 <td>@Html.DisplayFor( modelItem => (Convert.ToDateTime(item.ExpiryDate) -  DateTime.Now).Days, new {@class = item.class} ) </td>
```